# How to fix 'Office.Interlop -2146822384: Cannot edit Range' in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am creating a quote generator that takes word doc templates and replaces key words in the template to generate a quote. Afterwards the document is returned as a PDF file. There are a few sections of the template that need to be removed if there is no data to fill them out.

Currently there is a table row that could have 2 different notes attached to it. If there are no notes to add, there is a lot of white space in the row if I don't delete these lines.

This is a Windows form App Using the .NET Framework in Visual studios. I have search for this error on Sack-overflow and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word API and have not been able to find a similar issue. Originally I was using the same range object to do the search and delete. So I tried making a new range object but I still get the same issue.

I have put some code here:

```
//If there is data to add
if (temp.DATAOBJECT != null){
    FindAndReplace(_word, "<<Add-on Note PRODUCT>>", temp.DATAOBJECT, 1);
}else{
    //////HERE IS WHERE THE FIRST RANGE IS DELETED. THIS ONE WORKS///////
    range.Find.Execute("<<Add-on Note PRODUCT>>");
    range.Expand(WdUnits.wdParagraph); 
    range.Delete();
}
//If there is data to add
if (temp.DATAOBJECT != null){
    FindAndReplace(_word, "<<Add-on Note LINE>>", temp.DATAOBJECT, 1);
}else{
    ///HERE IS WHERE THE SECOND RANGE IS DELETED. THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK///
    range2.Find.Execute("<<Add-on Note LINE>>");
    range2.Expand(WdUnits.wdParagraph); 
    range2.Delete();
}
```

I have succeeded in deleting one of these line notes but when I attempt to delete the second line I get the error "Error -2146822384: Cannot edit Range."

I can not just make the line blank with "" because it leaves to much white space. It must be deleted.

Comment: You say these are in table cells? My best guess, without actually seeing it, is that `range2` probably contains table/cell structures that can't be deleted. To trouble-shoot this kind of thing I usually put a `range2.Select();` in there (just before the delete in this case), then stop code execution and look at what's selected. And try pressing Delete as a user to see if I can do it manually. If this doesn't help you, please post a screen shot of the selected `range2`.

Comment: Ah, follow-up question: Is there any kind of protection in this document? Content controls?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't believe there are any protections on the document. I will see what the select returns shortly and post it here

Comment: The range object that works is "<<Add-on Note PRODUCT>>\r"
The range 2 object text that is not working is "<<Add-on Note LINE>>\r\a"
I am new to Interlop so I am not sure what the "\a" is but that is probably what is causing the issue

Comment: Ah, yes. \a is the end-of-cell marker (ANSI 7) - a table structure. That means the Range needs to be backed off by one character. Something like (C# pseudo-code conversion from VBA because I can write that in my sleep): `range2.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);

Comment: Thank you, however it doesn't seem to have the intended effect I was looking for. It is leaving the empty line on the document instead of deleting the line

Comment: This is a table cell, which means it's in a table row with a particular height. Do you mean to delete the table row, or change the cell height? Or is there paragraph formatting applied somewhere that's affecting the row height?

Comment: The particular cell I am editing the table has the following Information:
<<Part No>>
<<Description>>
<<Add-on Note PRODUCT>>
<<Add-on Note LINE>>
All of which gets replaced or deleted from the cell except the "Add-on Note LINE" which stays. I don't need the cell deleted, just that line in the cell. Do you think that change the height of the row would do the trick?

Comment: Mmm, this discussion in comments has gotten too long - we're being prompted to move it to chat.. And this is a new problem, really, that's due to unfamiliarity with how Word works... I suggest you post this as a *new question* and include a screen shot of the problem part of the table. Before you take the screen shot, make sure to turn on the display of non-printing control characters (the "backwards P" in the Home tab of the Ribbon) so that some of the structural information is visible. Also, if the table does not have borders, make sure the table girdlines are visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @CindyMeister in the comments We have found out why the error is happening.

The range in questions was selecting the end of a cell in a table which also selects the"\a" tag that signifies the end of the cell. We can not call Delete on this range if the \a tag is selected. Here is the updated code:

```
//If there is data to add
if (temp.DATAOBJECT != null){
  FindAndReplace(_word, "<<Add-on Note LINE>>", temp.DATAOBJECT, 1);
}else{
  range2.Find.Execute("<<Add-on Note LINE>>");
  range2.Expand(WdUnits.wdParagraph); 
  range2.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
  range2.Delete();
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: Dear lord.. I was wondering what the "\a" means, couldn't find it in the Internet. Spent over 12 hours trying to figure out why delete isn't working. Thanks a lot mate!